# Replacing part of a string with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I know that some form of this question has been asked multiple times over, but I can't seem to get any of the solutions I've found to work. I have a line in a file that looks something like:

`<package foo="bar" unique-identifier="NEEDS_TO_BE_REPLACED" version="foobar">`

I need to replace the part indicated above, but I seem to always change unwanted information as well. The text that needs to be replaced is different from file to file, so currently I'm using a wildcard in it's place. Below are the things I've tried.

`sed 's/unique\-identifier\=\".*\"/unique\-identifier\=\"NEW_TEXT\"/g' $file >> $newFile`

`sed 's/\bunique\-identifier\=\".*\"\b/unique\-identifier\=\"NEW_TEXT\"/g' $file >> $newFile`

`sed 's/\<unique\-identifier\=\".*\"\>/unique\-identifier\=\"NEW_TEXT\"/g' $file >> $newFile`

`sed 's/[[:<:]]unique\-identifier\=\".*\"[[:>:]]/unique\-identifier\=\"NEW_TEXT\"/g' $file >> $newFile`

All of those are various solutions that I've found, the last being Mac OSX specific. Ideally I'd like to be able to replace just what's in the double-quotes, but my regex skills are lacking.

Comment: note: `*` is greedy!

Comment: Note: don't use text processing tools when working with markup!

Comment: Editing markup with sed will end in pain (because no one expects their XML-handling tools to break when the formatting changes). That looks like XML. Is it XML? If it is XML, use `xmlstarlet ed -u '//package/@unique-identifier[.="NEEDS_TO_BE_REPLACED"]' -v 'NEW_TEXT'` or so.

Comment: Thanks, @Wintermute. I've never heard of or used that, but I just brewed it and will be looking into it in the next few days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
sed 's/unique\-identifier\=\"[^"]*\"/unique\-identifier\=\"NEW_TEXT\"/g' $file >> $newFile
                             ↑
```

The reason your first attempt failed is because `.*` is greedy and matches as much as it can provided that the rest of the expression can be matched as well. In this case it matched also `" version="foobar`, and the rest of the expression (`\"`) matched the last character.

Replacing `.*` with `[^"]` makes this part match everything that is not `"`.

You could also remove repetitions and unnecessary escapes in your expression to make it more readable, like this:

```
sed 's/\(unique-identifier="\)[^"]*/\1NEW_TEXT/g' $file >> $newFile
```

Comment: Thanks! Like I said, my regex game is weak, so making it pretty definitely isn't my strong suit at the moment. I haven't tried your shortened solution, but theong form woks great